# Как повысить точность ИИ?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, искусственный-интеллект

У меня стоит здача типизации спектограмм, для этого я написал ИИ с данной моделью

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(16, (5, 5), padding='same', input_shape=(223, 217, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(128, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(256, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer="adam",
          metrics=['accuracy'])

result = model.fit(train_dataset, 
                validation_data=validation_dataset,
                epochs=100,
                verbose=2)
```

По итогу процент на validation около 65, а хотел бы добиться 80. Что можно использовать?

Comment: Слишком мало данных вы предоставили. Кривую обучения рисовали? Может 100 эпох просто мало, например. А может деление на трейн и валидацию неравномерное. А может ещё 100500 разных причин быть.

Comment: Сколько у вас экземпляров в обучающей выборке?